# Nuxt static generation produces us-ascii encoding instead of utf-8

Tags: utf-8, nuxt.js

Cyrillic symbols aren't displayed properly when opening Nuxt statically generated sources: word `Русский` outputs as `Ð ÑƒÑ\x81Ñ\x81ÐºÐ¸Ð¹`. Option `meta: [ { charset: 'utf-8' } ]` is already specified in `nuxt.config.js` file.

`enca` encoding detection utility says that files having `us-ancii` encoding: `7bit ASCII characters`
and `file -i`: `./index.html: text/html; charset=us-ascii`

Is there a way to force Nuxt `v2.15.7` static generation to output `utf` files instead of `us-ancii`?

Comment: The symptom looks like you are getting UTF-8 but your browser's settings (or something) causes it to be rendered as probably CP1252 or some other legacy 8-bit Western character set. How exactly is _Русский_ encoded in `index.html`?

Comment: @tripleee no, Nuxt generates files that `enca` and `file` Linux tools describe as having `us-ancii` encoding which has 7 bits and incapable of representing non-latin chars. Both tools also say that sources that contain `Русский` string constant (`nuxt.config.js` file) have `utf-8` encoding.

Comment: Then the encoding of `index.html` is completely uninteresting here. The crucial debugging detail which we still need is why your browser does not render it as UTF-8. Debugging that is a common FAQ as such; but as a quick first stab, does the server output the correct headers? Does the HTML contain a correct character set designation?

Comment: @tripleee why resulting encoding of generated `index.html` might not be relevant? Maybe I completely misunderstand how encodings work, but if Nuxt outputted `us-ascii` files, then `Русский` info will be just killed and no system would restore it to display properly?

Comment: But it seems that's not what's happening here. Perhaps review [the Stack Overflow `character-encoding` tag info page](/tags/character-encoding/info). I'm not familiar with Nuxt but the output you report looks like UTF-8, just not rendered correctly. In Python, `'Русский'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')` produces
`'Ð\xa0Ñ\x83Ñ\x81Ñ\x81ÐºÐ¸Ð¹'`

Comment: @tripleee so it means that `enca` and `file` tools misinterpret proper encoding of Nuxt-generated files as `us-ancii` and it's actually `utf-8`, but properly understands `nuxt.config.js` encoding as `utf-8`? Or it means that `us-ascii` encoding can store string `Русский`?

Comment: @tripleee that's what I think indeed happening: Nuxt takes my sources (which are `utf-8`) and decodes them as `latin-1` before outputting to files.

Comment: (That's "ASCII", not "ANCII".) Again, I don't know anything about Nuxt, but I'm guessing the contents of `index.html` are not relevant for your question, and that the file is indeed pure ASCII. (If its contents are important for what's happening here, probably share the contents of the file in the question.)

Comment: What I'm trying to persuade you to at least clarify is whether Nuxt is in fact operating correctly, and the problem is elsewhere in the process. Again, what you are reporting sounds like Nuxt is doing what it should, but something else persuades your browser to wreck the result.

Comment: @tripleee I clarify: Nuxt is killing the information by wrongfully converting `utf-8` encoding to `us-ancii` as `enca` and `file` Linux tools report.

Comment: You seem to think that, but we can't see why.

Comment: @tripleee I think so just because `enca` and `file` tools say that outputted files having `us-ancii` encoding :) - maybe it was an easy way for me after figuring out the problem for hours, but I would really like to see `enca` saying that files having `utf-8` encoding as it says about my sources which Nuxt compiles.